# Error with PECL command in PHP7

Tags: ubuntu, php, pecl, php7

I've upgraded php to version 7 and now I have problems with pecl command. When I run `sudo pecl install mongo` I get long list of errors:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249
```

I've tried solutions from this question: [PECL command produces long list of errors](https://serverfault.com/questions/589877/pecl-command-produces-long-list-of-errors)
but it's not working.
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with PHP7, I installed `php-dev` package

Answer (score 7):

You need to install those extensions

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear
sudo apt-get install php-xml php7.0-xml
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case on Ubuntu there was php7.1 (fpm) AND php7.2 (cli) installed.

Switching the cli explicitly to php7.1 using

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.1
sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize7.1
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config7.1
```

fixes the problem for me.

Answer (score -3):

Install php-xml with apt-get:

```
 sudo apt-get install php-xml php7.0-xml
```